# Why does it take so long for a user's account to update after activity?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that my account summary often lags notably from my activity. It may take 30+ minutes, for example, for my account summary to log a vote I make. Why is this?

Comment: Because with +3,000,000 users, instant updates for every action would be far too expensive on the servers.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cache the page for performance reasons.

There isn't anything there that needs to be updated instantly.